# sshfs has no installation candidate - universe repository installed

Tags: package-management, sshfs

I have tried to install `sshfs` in ubuntu, but I keep getting this error stating: `Package 'sshfs' has no installation candidate` (also shown below).

I saw in a similar post that the `sshfs` package has been moved to the universe repository, but even with installing that I still got the same error message. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sshfs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sshfs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Really? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=bin%2Fsshfs&searchon=contents

Comment: Please edit your post and provide the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file - and also your Ubuntu version.

Comment: I have a separate sshfs package installed from universe repo on [Focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/sshfs): `apt policy sshfs` -> `Installed: 3.6.0+repack+really2.10-0ubuntu1` - ssh is not a metapackage.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get update` too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)